# Force subdirectory of rspec specs to run serially in CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, circleci

We have a CircleCI setup that runs our rspec tests in parallel. I have a subdirectory, `spec/features` that uses capybara to do integration testing. They all pass locally when I run them serially, but when they are run in parallel, I get a lot of failures. This is most likely from some database state leaking into other tests that are running at the same time.

Is there a way to force CircleCI to run some directories serially? I know from the docs that you can [manually run directories in parallel](https://circleci.com/docs/parallel-manual-setup), but I haven't found a way to manually run something *not* in parallel.

I guessed that adding this to `circle.yml` might work:

```
 test:
 +  override:
 +    - bundle exec rspec:
 +        parallel: false
 +        files:
 +          - spec/features/checkout/**/*.rb
```

But it didn't. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Better contact CircleCi support.

Comment: Tests run in parallel in Circle run on different instances, so I don't think your problem is leakage between tests running at the same time. I'd look in to whether any tests depend on other tests having run before them, which would stop being the case when they were parallelized.